# Name that Song (part dos)

Tags: rebus, knowledge, computer-puzzle

Below is a rebus set, each of which unveils the lyrics of a song. Your job is to name the song and artist, as well as provide a translation for the rebus elements.

1.

$\delta{u(mind)} \approx \delta{girl(clothes)}$

2.

```
%> echo drunk > choir ; touch -t 07180000 choir
%> cmp my_goals choir
%>
```

3.

```
Person p1 = new Child();
Person p2 = new Person();
p1.age();
Person i = p2.spawnWith(p1);
i.name = p2.name;
i.gender = kFemale;
i.age();
```

**Note** (hint?): I expect 2 and 3 to be tricky for most people under the age of 30.

**Hint**:

> #3 might be easier to get if you read from bottom to top.

**Hint 2**:

> #3 is a song pleading for a divine entity that calls Alabama home.

**Hint 3**:

> #3 was released on a self-titled album in 1971 by a Chicago-based country/folk artist.

Comment: I'm 30 and number 3 is still tricky.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**#1**

> Hot and Cold by Katy Perry

Lyrics:

> `You change your mind
>  Like a girl changes clothes`

**#3**

> Angel from Montgomery by John Prine

Lyrics:

> `I am an old woman named after my mother 
>  My old man is another child that's grown old`

Explanation:

> p1 is the father 
>  p2 is the mother
>  i is "me"
>  `i.age(); and i.gender = kFemale;` $->$ I am an old woman
>  `i.name = p2.name;` $->$ named after my mother
>  `Person i = p2.spawnWith(p1);` $->$ p2 and p1 are the parents of i
>  `p1.age();`  $->$ My old man 
>  `Person p1 = new Child();`  $->$ is another child

Answer (score 8):

2. The song and artist are:

> "[Bird on the Wire](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/leonardcohen/birdonthewire.html)" by Leonard Cohen

Explanation:

> The rebus represents the lyrics "like a drunk in a midnight choir".

%> echo drunk > choir ; touch -t 07180000 choir

> The `echo` command created a file named `choir` containing the text `drunk`.  This represents a drunk being in a choir.
>
>  Then the `touch` command set the timestamp on the `choir` file to July 18 00:00 (midnight).  This represents a drunk being in a midnight choir.

%> cmp my_goals choir
%>

> The `cmp` command compared the files `my_goals` and `choir` and did not find any differences.  Therefore you could say the `my_goals` file is "like a drunk in a midnight choir".